# Hiding folder and redirecting with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently there is code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.zone$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.zone$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.zone\/folder" [R=301,L]
```

which redirecting users from subdomain.domain.zone to subdomain.domain.zone/folder/

I want users to see direct address without /folder/ in address bar, but to work with site which is in this /folder/. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved other way, have changed structure.

Answer (score 0):

Then you don't want to redirect. Get rid of the hostname and the `R` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.zone$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.domain\.zone$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Can probably simplify a bit more:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.zone$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: But the site is in the /folder/ and I can't move it from there. Your way is loading files from subdomain.domain.zone when I need to load site from /folder/, but to show in the address bar that it is direct address. Maybe it is not even possible?!

Comment: @user2314517 is `/folder/` not part of the document root where the htaccess file is in? If not then you need to create an `Alias` in the subdomain's vhost config.

Comment: I have roots like 'public_html/.htaccess', 'public_html/folder/', 'public_html/folder2/'. '/folder2/' is connected with the 'domain.zone'

Comment: @user2314517 and do you have a folder `public_html/folder/`?

Comment: Edited previous comment... Yes, i do.

Comment: @user2314517 then I don't understand what the problem is, if you go to `http://subdomain.domain.zone/` you get served the contents of `/folder/`

Comment: No I am not and I don't know why is it happening. It loads resources not from /folder/, but from the root.

Comment: @user2314517 because you had it setup to only match the `/` request, and not anything else. The regex `^/?$` won't match `/images/foo.gif`. The regex needs to be changed and a condition needs to be added to prevent looping

Comment: maybe the problem is with cms in root directory. because nothing helps - it still loading files from root, not from /folder/.

Comment: @user2314517 are there other rules in this htaccess file? You'll need to put these before any other routing rules

Comment: rules are in the beginning.